# How can we show the result in same page using ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
    Here is my calculatioform.jsp which accept two number.
```

when I press submit button it will display the result which contains addition, subtraction, multiplication and division in the same calculationFrom.jsp using ajax and jquery.

the jquery and ajax I am using to get the response is.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
          $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $(".button").click(function() {  
           var str = $("form").serialize();
        var str = $("form").serialize();
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "GET",  
                    url: "calculator.jsp",  
                    data: str,  
                    cache:false,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function(data) {  
                           var msg = data.val1 + " + " + data.val2 + " = " + data.sum;
                            alert(msg);
                    }  
                });  
                return false;


This is my calulator.jsp page on clicking submit button the request go to this
```

page.It will take two parameter from form and do calculation.The input value is
 store in Val1 and Val2. based on this i calculate the result.

```
                String result = "({";
                result += " val1 : " + val1 + ",";
                result += " val2 : " + val2 + ",";
                result += " sum : " + (val1 + val2) + ",";
```

But this code is not working. what I need to do so that the code will work.

Comment: not working means what?getting errors or not satisfactory output or what?

Comment: in your success callback, data is undefined... And please, check your console!

Comment: @javaBeginner no there is no error but nothing will happens after click on submit button

Answer (score 4):

you are not defining `data` in your success callback function definition

```
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "calculator.jsp",  
            data: str,  
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {  //you need data defined
```

Depending on what data is being returned you might need to specify the return type by using `dataType` option

```
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "calculator.jsp",  
            data: str,  
            cache:false,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {
               //access properties through data
               var msg = data.val1 + " + " + data.val2 + " = " + data.sum + '\n';
```

**Additional Edit**

Also it looks like you have the click event attached to the submit button which is probably causing the script to submit to itself or whatever page you have set in the `action` attribute, you need to have it cancel the default action by using `preventDefault`

```
$(".button").click(function(e) { //e will hold the event object
           e.preventDefault() //prevents the default action of the event, 
                              //in this case the form submission
           var str = $("form").serialize();
```

you may also be getting a parse error, you can set an error callback as well

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "calculator.jsp",  
    data: str,  
    cache:false,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {  
       var msg = data.val1 + " + " + data.val2 + " = " + data.sum;
        alert(msg);
    },
    error:function(xhr,errormsg) {
       alert(errormsg);
    }  
});
```

Comment: what is not working? do you have any errors in your javascript console? Also what is the data being retrieved as you have `eval(data)`, jquery can automatically parse data like json,xml,html, etc so you probably do not need eval

Comment: No I am not getting any error. But when I press submit button.There is no change in the page.

Comment: you also have not prevented the default action of the form submission which among just submiting the page it will cause the ajax request to stop as the page is being changed, see latest edit about that

Comment: But after the ajax call I add return false. I think it will do the same thing

Comment: it does, didnt see the return false, but if there is an error before the return false the form will be submitted and you will not see any errors in the console as you will basically be on a new page. Depending on which browser you are using you can tell the javascript console to preserve console messages on navigation. I suspect your script is erroring out somewhere but you are not getting the errors as the form gets submitted and changes the page. try setting the console to preserve the console message.

Comment: also if your data being retrieved is not valid jquery will not execute the success function, it will instead try to execute a error callback function, look at latest edit to see setting an error callback.

Comment: Yes I am getting error Message. means ther is a problem in Second jsp.

Comment: if you are getting a parse error then that means your output of your json is invalid, make sure you are outputting the json data correctly, you can check the output at www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn").click(function(){
                    var marks1=$("#marks1").val();
                    var marks2=$("#marks2").val();
                    var option=$("input:radio:checked").val();
                    var str = $("form").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'Operation',
                        data:{  marks1:marks1,
                            marks2:marks2,
                            option:option
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                           //Do something
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a response by your web method

```
 $(function(){ 
       $(".button").click(function() {  
          var str = $("form").serialize();
          $.ajax({  
               type: "GET",  
               url: "calculator.jsp",  
               data: str,  
               cache:false,
               success: function(response) {  
              }
         });
    });
```